# RichApi.Error: There was an internal error while processing the request

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-tables, excel-web-addins

I have developed an Excel Javascript plugin using the React framework.

The add-in workflow is simple.

Request data from Ui using APIs
Passing entities' column names and authorized API keys
Start writing data into an active Excel sheet by pulling the button.

Steps to reproduce

1. Open the Excel file
2. Select the criteria for pulling data
3. Open another Excel file
4. Again Select the criteria for pulling data
5. Pull the data at a time with a button click.

Problem :
The table got printed only in one Excel sheet only. In another Excel sheet, I got the below error.

**RichApi.Error: There was an internal error while processing the request.
at new n (excel-win32-16.01.js:25:259407)
at i.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (excel-win32-16.01.js:25:323853)
at excel-win32-16.01.js:25:321916**

I had tried below code:

```
try {
    var i = 0;
    // these data are coming from APIs
    var allCompanies = [12, 32, 33, 43, 45, 66, 12, 32, 10, 12, 21, 90];
    allCompanies.forEach(async _company => {
      // calling APIs for each _docs and writing data for that companies
      await fetchData(_company).then(async (responseRows) => {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
          let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
          sheet.load(["name"]);
          await context.sync();
          for (let i = 0; i < responseRows.length; i++) {
            // data operations into Exel sheet
            // creating table, table header, applying Css
            // writting value to each cells
          }
          sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
          sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
          await context.sync();
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error on appending data into excel " + error);
  }
```

I don't know why I'm getting errors.

Can anyone have any idea about this error?

Comment: You should read about performance and optimal code writing for office-js. You should take your `context.sync()` out of the loops and `Excel.Run` out of the loops and you are using the same `active worksheet` for each loop, you perhaps want to define a worksheet if you have multiple worksheets and you should avoid writing to tables. Lots of issues here.

Comment: Means we need to specify in which worksheet we want to write data in table format?